# Related Rates question: A man starts walking north at 4 ft/s from a point P. Five minutes later a woman starts

Tags: calculus

A man starts walking north at 4 ft/s from a point P. Five minutes later a woman starts walking south at 5 ft/s from a point 500 ft due east of P. At what rate are the people moving apart 15 minutes after the woman starts walking? (Round your answer to two decimal places.)[image]

Comment: There’s no unique solution if all that happens a few meters away from the South Pole.

Answer (score 1):

The method is basically sound with one error.
In your figure, you have a right triangle with leg lengths $500$ and $4800+4500$.
The length of the hypotenuse of that triangle is
$\sqrt{(4800+4500)^2 + 500^2}$,
not $\sqrt{4800^2 + 4500^2 + 500^2}$.

Comment: Would the answer be 8.98 ft/s?

Comment: I get something between $8.98$ and $8.99$ that rounds up. Anyway, this is a lot more reasonable than $12.68$. After all the fastest they could walk away from each other is $9$ ft/s, and that's only if they are walking directly away along the same line.

Comment: The 8.98 was wrong.

Comment: As I said, the answer rounds _up_ in this case.